How to calculate the minimum luminous flux needed from an LED through multiple layers?
Say there is an RGB LED with a specific viewing angle and an observer viewing the LED (not necessarily at a 0-degree viewing angle). The observer and the LED are separated by multiple layers of different materials. How would you calculate the minimum luminous flux for the observer to see the LED?

This may or may not be a focused question for this site, but 1. Attenuation of light through materials can be done with Beer's law. 2. You may need the Fresnel equations for the interfaces between the materials. 3. Your LED's spec sheet should have a diagram showing the relative flux at angles away from 0°.
